# How to fetch client system Date and Time on page load in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

I am working in a Angular 4 project ,In this I need to get the client system's Date and Time on page load and pass it to the API for storing the data in MSSQL server.

I have done all the API and MSSQL parts but I Don't know how to get the Client system's date and time ...

Comment: I don't think, that it is possible to get OS info through javascript.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow ! you should put some snipped of code you have tried so we can help you to get through this.

Comment: @Markz  `new Date()` will in your angular code will give client date time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Angular (so TypeScript) `new Date()` get the current date and time, so:

```
let myDate: Date = new Date();
```